# Unable to create this stored procedure in cPanel

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cpanel

When entered as a MySQL query the following code returns this error:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE getId ( IN p_email VARCHAR(60) , OUT p_id INT ) BEGIN S' at line 2"

Is the problem actually in that particular line?

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getId
CREATE PROCEDURE getId
(
  IN p_email VARCHAR(60)
, OUT p_id INT
)
BEGIN
SELECT id
INTO p_id
FROM accounts
WHERE email = p_email;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a ; at the end of line 2